# how to remove top or root class from child element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

I am trying to transpile this `scss to css`

**input**

```
.abc{
  .slider {
    $root: &;
    &--fade {
      > #{$root}__track {
        > #{$root}__list {
          > #{$root}__slide {
            .rh08w5 {
              opacity: 0;
              h2 {
                opacity: 0;
              }
             
           
            }
          
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
.abc .slider--fade > .abc .slider__track > .abc .slider__list > .abc .slider__slide .rh08w5 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.abc .slider--fade > .abc .slider__track > .abc .slider__list > .abc .slider__slide .rh08w5 h2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**expected output**

```
.abc .slider--fade > .slider__track > .slider__list > .slider__slide .rh08w5 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.abc .slider--fade > .slider__track > .slider__list > .slider__slide .rh08w5 h2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

In my output `.abc` class added in all item . I want it should add only on top element ?

how to remove `.abc` class from child element

Comment: If I would see such a css selector, my code smell detector would ring an alarm! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)
It seems odd to me that you need such deep specificity, maybe approaching the problem from a different perspective would be more beneficial: try to simplify the css selector and maybe you won't need to remove the `.abc` class at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using the parent selector. The only way I can think of is to store the `.slider` class in your root variable instead:

```
.abc {
  $root: ".slider";

  #{$root} {
    &--fade {
      > #{$root}__track {
        > #{$root}__list {
          > #{$root}__slide {
            .rh08w5 {
              opacity: 0;
              h2 {
                opacity: 0;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just manually edit it if it is only these two lines. Another way would be to delete the .abc class before you convert it and add it back to your CSS only where you want it.